# How to undo patches you made to linux kernel in ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, kernel, network-manager

I recently installed driver for my bluetooth adapter on ubuntu 18.04. To install the driver, it first required to make a patch to the kernel. So, i did it. Now, I am facing a problem of unresponsiveness of system. Cursor is working fine, but No GUI software is opening and also network manager is getting off. I suspect, that it might be due to that patch as this problem didn't occur before that. Plese help.

`System: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS`

`Kernel version: 5.3.0-45-generic`

Comment: During boot, and using `grub` select another older *un-patched* kernel  (depending on your setup, you may need to press a key for the `grub` menu to appear)

Comment: okay, i will do this. Can i automate this process of selecting older un-patched kernel during boot?